Can the auto-print feature be used in the browser (Edge, Chrome)?
I would like the print() function in JavaScript to automatically print to the default printer when using Edge or Chrome browsers.
I am aware that adding the -kiosk command to the shortcut can enable this functionality. However, my customers cannot make these modifications themselves and are very reluctant to read the manual. It is really unfortunate
Our service is still small, so we are using a mix of WPF applications and web. This is because WPF allows direct printing to the computer's printer
Therefore, I want to enable direct printing from anywhere
I considered determining the program installation status via socket communication from the web page to the local (user's computer) and guiding the installation of the program, which would then handle printing through a C# console application. However, this approach seemed terrible, so I did not pursue it
A colleague mentioned that there might be a way to trigger the print button event in the printer dialog screen using JavaScript. Although I don't think this is a feasible method, I am hopeful about this possibility. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated

Browsers will not let you print automatically without user intervention. Think about this, this would let a malicious website take over every visitor's printer.
